Start Azure Function but Disable EventHub Listener
When developing an Azure Function (C#) it would be nice to disable the eventhubs consumer and just use HTTP POST to http://localhost:$port/admin/functions/$FunctionName to locally trigger events. That way we are not bothered by the "noise" on the topic and can trigger our own events individually and locally.
Is there a configurable way to disable the eventhandler/trigger for EventHub only? I don't want to change code each time to enable/disable it should be a local config only.


By what the Function is triggered is more than "just" configuration. Some triggers do in fact support multi-trigger. For example TimerTrigger'ed functions can also be HTTP triggered by default. Don't know if that's possible for EHT. But even if it were, you'd still need a means to tell it to ignore the EH triggers ... Have you considered stuff like Feature-Flags and having parallel "wrapper" functions - one HTTP triggered, one EH triggered, both calling the same implementation but then you could "switch" on/off one of them?

Of course you could have a specialized topic, too. And then set SalesConditionEventOptions:Topic to that for local development.

BTW: Some people will downvote for "posting code as image not text".

@Marc, you can disable function by adding "AzureWebJobs.<Function_name>.Disabled": "true" in local.settings.json

@Marc, check if the below provided answer helps.

You can disable a specific function by adding the setting "AzureWebJobs.<Function_Name>.Disabled": "true" in local.settings.json.
I have created a function project with an Event Hub trigger and a Http trigger function.
Http Trigger:
 [Function("Function1")]
 public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
     return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
 }

Event Hub Trigger:
 [Function(nameof(EventHubFunction))]
 public void Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "connectionstring")] EventData[] events)
 {
     foreach (EventData @event in events)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Event Body: {body}", @event.Body);
         _logger.LogInformation("Event Content-Type: {contentType}", @event.ContentType);
     }
 }

local.settings.json:
Disabled EventHubTrigger by adding AzureWebJobs.Function_Name.Disabled setting in local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobs.EventHubFunction.Disabled": "true",
    "connectionString": "<EventHub_connectionstring>"
  }
}

Response:
[2024-11-08T09:42:26.486Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 20736) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-11-08T09:42:26.538Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Http_Trigger: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7142/api/Http_Trigger

Function EventHubFunction is disabled.
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-08T09:42:31.231Z] Executing 'Functions.Http_Trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=114e9d63-917d-4fe0-a989-15516c04b847)
[2024-11-08T09:42:31.610Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-08T09:42:31.700Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-11-08T09:42:31.706Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-11-08T09:42:31.799Z] Executed 'Functions.Http_Trigger' (Succeeded, Id=114e9d63-917d-4fe0-a989-15516c04b847, Duration=596ms)




I know how to disable the function - I want to keep it enabled but not have it triggered by events. So I can test it by sending it events via HTTP only.

You can specify the function that should be run in host.json { "functions":[ "FunctionName_ToRun" ]}
